# R mtcars dataset, manual transmission

Tags: r

I would greatly appreciate help on this task:

Show all names of cars in the mtcars data set that have manual transmissions. Show both your R code and the list of car names. HINT: You may want to use rownames() to access the car names.

Comment: Your question reads like a challenge or quiz, is this homework?

Comment: If you look at `mtcars$am`, you see a vector of 0s and 1s. If you do `mtcars$am == 1`, you'll see a vector of trues and falses indicating which are and are not manual transmission. When you index on a vector, you can index by number or by boolean, so compare `1:10`, `(1:10)[c(2,5)]`, and `(1:10)[c(F,T,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F)]`. Use this information to index on your vector of `rownames(mtcars)`.

Comment: Can you post the code for what you have tried so far? The goal of Stack Overflow isn't to solve problems from scratch, but rather to assist with troubleshooting existing code that isn't working as expected.

Comment: BTW, nick: my question is not to suggest that homework is not allowed on SO, [***it is allowed***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), though many suggest that you say as such up front so that the answers can be massaged to your apparent level of R and/or statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [subsetting](https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) as well as `rownames` function you can extract names of cars with manual transmission:

```
data(mtcars)
rownames(mtcars[mtcars$am == 1, ])
```

Output:

```
 [1] "Mazda RX4"      "Mazda RX4 Wag"  "Datsun 710"     "Fiat 128"       "Honda Civic"    "Toyota Corolla"
 [7] "Fiat X1-9"      "Porsche 914-2"  "Lotus Europa"   "Ford Pantera L" "Ferrari Dino"   "Maserati Bora" 
[13] "Volvo 142E"
```